# Поворот текста

Tags: html, css

Есть ли какя-нибудь возможность поворота текста (DIV'а) на 90<sup>0</sup> методами CSS. Либо JavaScript.  Кроме SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.by/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82+css&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&client=opera&hs=8ce&rls=ru&channel=suggest&sa=X&ei=OtuzTuq7IsqJ4gTYg5zWAw&ved=0CBcQvwUoAQ&q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82+css&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=1ec34185141edb88&biw=1680&bih=928) даёт развернутый ответ.